# Installing Windows 10 on Lenovo ThinkCentre

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, uefi, desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre that has a Win7 Pro install that's been upgraded to Win 10 Pro. During/shortly afterwards the HDD started failing, so I thought it might be a good idea to do a fresh install of Windows 10 to a SSD.

I installed a Samsung 850 Pro, and now when I boot the Windows 10 installer from a USB stick (USB3.0 stick, 2.0 Port), I get the "can't create partition error" when I try to select/partition the SSD. It recognizes the SSD just fine, but I can't find any way to get it to actually install to the drive.

I've tried the following:

- Setting the SATA controller to ATA-mode (was in AHCI before) - didn't
  work.
- Partitioning the drive according to [these instructions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2012/03/06/error-we-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one-for-more-information-see-the-setup-log-files-when-you-try-to-install-windows-8-cp/) (didn't
  work)
- Setting the BIOS on the Lenovo to enable "Legacy Free", which disables P/S2, serial, parallel etc. so I guess this is enablin UEFI boot (didn't work).

I'm all out of ideas, anybody got something else? I'm thinking of doing an install to the old drive and then just cloning it over to the SSD, but I've understood that this is less than optimal when it comes to SSDs.

Comment: Did this SSD have a partition before you installed it?

Comment: What I suspect your problem is attempt to use a USB 3.0 device on a USB 2.0 port.  Try using a physical installation disk or a different USB media device.

Comment: @Ramhound You were right, recreated the media on a USB 2.0 stick and the installer worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a installations media USB3.0 stick and a USB2.0 port was the problem, I changed over to a USB2.0 stick and it worked perfectly!